# How to work around absence of futimes() in android (NDK)?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, bionic

I have large project which needs `futimes` or `futimens` function. Unfortunately there are no such functions in header files in android ndk include folder. Is there a work-around (stub or simple code snippet using existing functions)?

Documentation for the `futimes` function can be found [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lutimes.3.html).

Comment: By `futime()` function you mean a function that records the modification time of a file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`futimes(3)` is a non-POSIX function that takes a `struct timeval` (seconds, microseconds).  The POSIX version is `futimens(3)`, which takes a `struct timespec` (seconds, nanoseconds).  The latter is available in bionic libc.

**Update**: I'm afraid I got a little ahead of myself.  The code is [checked into AOSP](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/63321/) but isn't available yet.

However... if you look at the code, `futimens(fd, times)` is implemented as `utimensat(fd, NULL, times, 0)`, where `utimensat()` is a Linux system call that does appear to be defined in the NDK.  So you should be able to provide your own implementation of `futimens()` based on the syscall.

**Update:** It made it into bionic but not the NDK.  Here's how to roll your own:

```
// ----- utimensat.h -----
#include <sys/stat.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
int utimensat(int dirfd, const char *pathname,
        const struct timespec times[2], int flags);
int futimens(int fd, const struct timespec times[2]);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// ----- utimensat.c -----
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include "utimensat.h"
int utimensat(int dirfd, const char *pathname,
        const struct timespec times[2], int flags) {
    return syscall(__NR_utimensat, dirfd, pathname, times, flags);
}
int futimens(int fd, const struct timespec times[2]) {
    return utimensat(fd, NULL, times, 0);
}
```

Add those to your project, include the utimensat.h header, and you should be good to go.  Tested with NDK r9b.

(This should be wrapped with appropriate ifdefs (e.g. `#ifndef HAVE_UTIMENSAT`) so you can disable it when the NDK catches up.)

**Update:** AOSP change [here](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/69602).

Comment: I was not able to find any header file with `futimens` definition in neither standalone toolchain folder (used `make-standalone-toolchain` script) nor ndk folder. Used ndk-r9 (the latest available)

Comment: `utimensat` does not work for me. When I grep over my android-ndk-r9 folder I can neither find `utimensat` nor `futimens`. Neither is defined in `sys/stat.h`. Is there anything special I need to include?