# Android: Find out which core the thread is running on

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm trying to write code for Android which would give me some kind of information (id?) of the processor and the core on which a thread is running on.

I've google'd and grep'ed the sources for some inspiration but with no luck. All I know is, that most likely I will need some C/C++ calls.

What I have working is the following:

```
#include <jni.h>

int getCpuId() {
    // missing code
    return 0;
}

int getCoreId() {
    // missing code    
    return 0;
} 

JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_spendoptima_Utils_getCpuId(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject obj) {
    return getCpuId();
}

JNIEXPORT int JNICALL Java_com_spendoptima_Utils_getCoreId(JNIEnv * env,
        jobject obj) {
    return getCoreId();
}
```

The whole project compiles and runs just fine. I'm able to call the functions from within Java and I get the proper responses.

Is here anybody who could fill in the blanks?

Comment: Are you looking for `getcpu()` / `sched_getcpu()`?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/491520/how-can-i-get-the-cpu-core-number-from-within-a-user-space-app-linux-c

Comment: As far as I know, sched_getcpu has been implemented only for the mips archictecture. I tried to port it to arm, but got a compilation error. __getcpu could not be found, or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The good news is, the necessary library and system call are defined on Android ([sched_getcpu()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/kitkat-release/libc/bionic/sched_getcpu.c) and [__getcpu()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/kitkat-release/libc/arch-arm/syscalls/__getcpu.S)).  The bad news is, they aren't part of the NDK.

You can roll your own syscall wrapper and library call, using the method shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374749/how-to-work-around-absence-of-futimes-in-android-ndk/19386377#19386377).

Another approach is to read `/proc/self/stat` and parse out the `processor` entry.  The [proc(5) man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) describes the format:

> ```
>   /proc/[pid]/stat
>          Status  information  about  the process.  This is used by ps(1).
>          It is defined in /usr/src/linux/fs/proc/array.c.
>   ...
>          processor %d (since Linux 2.2.8)
>                      CPU number last executed on.
> ```

This is much slower, and the "file" format may change if the kernel is updated, so it's not the recommended approach.

Answer (score 6):

This is what seems to work for me:

```
//...
#include <sys/syscall.h>
//...
int getCpuId() {

    unsigned cpu;
    if (syscall(__NR_getcpu, &cpu, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return (int) cpu;
    }
}
//...
```